# Regex - match until group that may or may not occur

Tags: regex, match, option-type

I have following text:

```
:3:Start!@#$%^&*():31:Start!@#$%^&*():31:End!@#$%^&*():3:End
```

and with following regex:

```
(:3:Start)(.*)(:31:Start.*:31:End)?(.*)(:3:End)
```

Why group3 is not found even though it exists. Even if I set group2 as not greedy:

```
(:3:Start)(.*?)(:31:Start.*:31:End)?(.*)(:3:End)
```

How Can I capture group with optional subgroup if it occurs in the middle of the text

Comment: Group 3 is composed of "##:20C::CORP" + group 4 and 5, so I take group 3 as one. So my goal is to capture group 1, group 2 and group 3 if group 3 exists. If group 3 does not exists then group 2 should take everything...

Comment: You could make the group 2 match non greedy with a positive lookahead asserting `##` like `(##:16R:GENL)(.*?(?=##))(##:20C::CORP(\/{1,2})([^##]*))?` https://regex101.com/r/I97qaP/1

Comment: Problem: Because `.*` in capture group 2 is greedy and you made the rest optional, it will consume any character upto end string before the optional capture group 3-5 have a chance. If you pattern always holds uppercase letters you could swap `.*` with `[A-Z]*`

Comment: If there can not be a `#` inbetween, you could use a negated character class like at the end of your pattern. Note that `[^#]*` is the same as `[^##]*` for example `(##:16R:GENL)([^#]*)(##:20C::CORP(\/{1,2})([^#]*))?` see https://regex101.com/r/xjCFzm/1

Comment: The thing is "everything can be" in between groups. Groups have similar structure but I'm only interested in specific ones and some of them may or may not occur.

Comment: Which of them do always occur?

Comment: Let's assume such text: ":3:Start!@#$%^&*():31:Start!@#$%^&*():31:End!@#$%^&*():3:End" - How can I extract ":31:Start!@#$%^&*():31:End" when this is optional. (:3:Start)(.*)(:31:Start.*:31:End)?(.*)(:3:End) this doesn't catch group3 even though it exists :-( https://regex101.com/r/tBtohF/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve what you need if you enclose the `(.*?)` and `(:31:Start.*:31:End)` groups into an optional non-capturing group (quantified with a greedy `?` quantifier) and making the optional group *obligatory*:

```
(:3:Start)(?:(.*?)(:31:Start.*:31:End))?(.*)(:3:End)
          |____________________________|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpLikK/1). It will work like this:

- `(:3:Start)` - will capture into Group 1 the :3:Start` string
- `(?:(.*?)(:31:Start.*:31:End))?` - will attempt to match once a sequence of patterns:

  - `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `(:31:Start.*:31:End)` - Group 3: `:31:Start.*:31:End` string
- `(.*)` - Group 4: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(:3:End)` - captures into Group 5 `:3:End` string

**Why doesn't your pattern work**?

See [your pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpLikK/2), the `!@#$%^&*():31:Start!@#$%^&*():31:End!@#$%^&*()` substring is captured into Group 4, matched with `(.*)` pattern. It happens because `(.*?)(:31:Start.*:31:End)?` first skips the `.*?` pattern (it is lazy, non-greedy, the engine does not even attempt to match it when it sees such a pattern the first time, it goes on matching with obligatory patterns and only comes back when the subsequent patterns do not match), and `(:31:Start.*:31:End)?` matches an empty string right after `:3:Start` substring. The rest finds a match, thus, no optional text is matched into your expected group.